# How to fix BSOD caused by ntoskrnl.exe?

Tags: ntoskrnl.exe

I'll be honest with you, I copied this text because I have similar problems. I have gone through all the steps below. I changed the power supply, changed the RAM, reinstalled Windows.

PC spec:

TUF B450-PLUS GAMING
Ryzen 5 3600
G.Skill F4 3200C16-8HTZR x2
GTX 1080TI Evga
Aerocool VX-600 600W

When I leave the computer on for a few minutes or hours (it doesn't matter if is on the desktop screen, working or playing heavy games), the BSOD (kmode exception not handled) appears and the system unexpectedly restarts.

I checked all the drivers and everything is up to date.
Checked RAM with MemTest for 8 hours, no errors.

I checked the HDD and SSD and both are fine.
I wonder how do I solve this problem?

I checked by the BlueScreenView software and the log that appeared about the BSOD was this:
KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED 0x0000001e  ffffffff`c0000005   fffff804`2f6382ab   00000000`00000000   ffffffff`ffffffff   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+42ec70                 x64 ntoskrnl.exe+42ec70

I completely reset the bios, pulled out the battery.
I ran "sfc/scannow" and found some errors, but they have been fixed and now everything is fine.
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth - all fine

No overclocking is worth it, I have never done this

I would be very grateful for the help, since I spent 2 weeks on this and no result.
A discussion with a similar error can be found many times on forms, but the way out of situations is different:
Reinstalling the driver helps someone, deleting some software, someone in high performance mode, but not for me, unfortunately .. I tried everything.

Last .dmp (mine ofc.)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EG7JuzyXODZrbZh7rMBwjy2zeZRveQhv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is it exactly that you're asking?

Comment: 1. Have you tried a malware scan? Some can persist even after Windows reinstall. 2. Have you tested RAM (not just changed it), *per* https://www.troubleshootingcentral.com/how-to-fix-the-kmode-exception-not-handled-error-0x0000001e/ 3. Try booting and running from USB, e.g. with Hirens CD or Linux... If that has issues, then it's almost certainly *hardware* at fault.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I tried checking for viruses exclusively using the built-in Windows utility. what antivirus do you recommend? "Try booting and running from USB" sorry I'm not very good at this, what should I do?

Comment: IMO you would be better off by asking on a more interactive type forum, where people can tell do this, then try that, what do you see, then do this .. What you present here is a needle / haystack type issue, it could be 100's on things. Could be that cleaning case or simply disconnect all components and reconnect fixes it. Or not.

Comment: Needle or no needle, but I described everything I could, and also attached a dmp, thinking that it would help for a lead. I don't know what else I can do. Thanks for that too, Mr. Joep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have posted a comment but I don't have enough room there to do so.  I will delete this "answer" once the information has been consumed.

This looks like a device driver or storage hardware problem to me.
I have far more data than you want to see.. but the error boils down to this:

MULTIPLE_IRP_COMPLETE_REQUESTS (44)
A driver has requested that an IRP be completed (IoCompleteRequest()), but
the packet has already been completed.  This is a tough bug to find because
the easiest case, a driver actually attempted to complete its own packet
twice, is generally not what happened.  Rather, two separate drivers each
believe that they own the packet, and each attempts to complete it.  The
first actually works, and the second fails.  Tracking down which drivers
in the system actually did this is difficult, generally because the trails
of the first driver have been covered by the second.  However, the driver
stack for the current request can be found by examining the DeviceObject
fields in each of the stack locations.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa8008734a00, Address of the IRP
Arg2: 0000000000000ec0
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

I am not allowed to show you everything that I can see but I can tell you that it is happening in a stub based on [this opensource file](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/main/storage/class/classpnp/src/xferpkt.c) which is what is making me think it is either an OI driver or the hardware itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I think I have found what the problem is.

Using WinDbg, one of the dumps has the following information:
PROCESS_NAME: steam.exe
Also, in a similar dump was:
PROCESS_NAME: EALocalHostSvc.exe

Comment: I play Fifa23, which is in the Steam library, redirecting when I start the game to the EA application and it seems to me that the problem is somewhere there.

So, I completely uninstalled Steam along with the FIFA game

I'll keep an eye on the situation and be sure to come back with an update if it helps me.

Once again I want to thank you for your great help.

Comment: The processes you are referring to are user mode applications.  A user mode application can not cause a blue screen.  Only a device driver, kernel flaw, or hardware can cause a blue screen.  If you can identify an application that can cause this, it is only because that application is able to make something in a driver happen.. not the application itself.

Comment: Also, I work at Microsoft and I am not able to share with you all of the things that I can see in the private symbols.  That is why I am being weird about it.  I like having a job.

Comment: Well, there was another crash last night.
This time, a different app, just like you said.

I'm attaching a fresh file, take a look at it, maybe there will be something new here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qGGp-eViKR-Zo1xXi9eZRdwF6McTGtuU/view?usp=sharing

And yet, I would like you to tell me in simple words after the analysis what I should do, at least approximately, give some recommendations, since I am at a loss.

Thank you!

Comment: After looking at the first dump.. compared with the second dump.  I would bet.. with 99% chance of probability that one of the drivers on your system is causing this problem.  My best bet would be a third party driver that you don't need or needs updating.  I am also guessing that it is with an I/O device like a hard drive that didn't need a driver in the first place.  Please understand that these are ALL guesses.  For all I know it is a Razer brand mouse.

Comment: I'll try disabling the mouse and see what happens

Also, today a person from reddit suggested this for my problem:

"It's not likely good news. The Ryzen 3600 cpu has a very high failure rate. Sub in a different cpu and see if you have the same problem"

I want to note that I came across discussions regarding the unreliability of the first released batches of Ryzen 5 3600 processors. After that, people replaced them and the problem went away

Comment: In addition:

In device manager, my mouse was listed as Razer Blackwidow Ultimate, although it's actually my keyboard model. The mouse is called the Razer Viper Mini.

Removed the device along with the driver for it. For now it is called HID - compatible mouse.

Also, for some reason, there are three of them

Comment: did not help, another one BSoD

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4wZDX-v4B0ATehlxTKzlNce6-AMtnaR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i will try to reinstall windows

Comment: Sorry for your woes.  I wish I could help more.

Comment: Reinstall Windows yesterday For now - ok

But now a strange thing, it happened before, very rarely, but still:

The PC just freez, nothing foreshadowed trouble, but at one point it just freez, not reacting to anything

Helped only reboot through the button

Comment: nope, another BSOD, I will try to change CPU .. fuck all this shit...

Comment: Update: new CPU installed a few days ago. The flight is normal, so far without BSODs

I'm monitoring the situation and will let you know if anything changes.

Comment: GOOD LUCK!!! :)

Comment: I forgot to clarify a very important detail: I took a new CPU from a friend, the same model 3600. Accordingly, he installed my problematic CPU in his PC. And, he has no BSODs just like me. I do not know how to explain it.

Comment: Perhaps it is how a card was seated that you bumped tighter when in the case.  Perhaps it was event the connection of the chipset itself.

Comment: what card are you talking about? (I'm not very good at English)

Comment: ANY of them.  Sometimes I fix machines by pulling out and putting back in all cards.  Sometimes I only wiggle them.  Your English is fine! :)

Comment: You can close the branch, the issue is resolved, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I would recommend:

1. update your bios/uefi and download the  update packages from the manufacturer of your motherboard
2. Scan the computer with sophos hitmanpro and kaspersky TDSSkiller (google them to find the downloads)
3. Boot into ubuntu and hiren's boot cd pe and see if they crash
4. If all else fails, take your pc to a repair shop to get it fixed

Comment: These are very good suggestions.